# How to write a SD/mmc program with Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, sd-card, spi, mmc

I bought a SD module like [this](https://www.taiwansensor.com.tw/product/arduino-micro-sd-%E8%A8%98%E6%86%B6%E5%8D%A1%E8%AE%80%E5%AF%AB%E6%A8%A1%E7%B5%84-micro-sdhc-%E5%8D%A1%E8%AE%80%E5%AF%AB%E5%8D%A1%E5%99%A8-spi%E4%BB%8B%E9%9D%A2/). I'd like to learn SD protocol with Raspberry Pi. I tried to write a example code with SPI mode. This is my [example code](https://codeshare.io/5eOgzl).

I sent `CMD0(0x40 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x95)` to SD module, and I expect I can receive 0x01(in idle state). My example code received `0xff`. How to modify my code to do? Where can I find SD/MMC sample programs with SPI mode?

Comment: Have you looked at the https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/mmc/host/mmc_spi.c? Note that MMC in SPI mode abuses the SPI protocol.

Comment: Thank you for your information. I am trying it now, and I also found the website it is very useful. http://www.rjhcoding.com/avrc-tutorials-home.php